# TensorFlow was not compiled to use AVX 5200

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu, nvidia

I have installed **Python 3.5**, **tensorflow-gpu 1.5**, **CUDA v.9**, **cuDNN v.7** and **NVIDIA AVX 5200**. Although, I have installed tensorflow, bit cannot be used in Python and returns the following exception:

```
2019-03-31 22:27:45.285194: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137]   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2019-03-31 22:27:46.132472: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with  properties:
name: NVS 5200M major: 2 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.344
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.00GiB freeMemory: 823.00MiB
2019-03-31 22:27:46.132585: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-  win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35   \tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1168] Ignoring visible gpu  device (device: 0, name: NVS 5200M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute  capability: 2.1) with Cuda compute capability 2.1. The minimum required Cuda         capability is 3.0.
```

And when checking it as:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get:

```
name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Your GPU ist too old and not supported (CUDA compute capability is too low). Please read the message carefully. The AVX stuff has nothing to do with the GPU.

Comment: @xdurch0 thank you for your reply. Please what can I do can you help me? I'm new in python.

Comment: You need a new GPU.